# How to subtract Sunday from datetime range in python

Tags: python, datetime

I have a datetime range in python that adds a bunch of dates to a range, but i can't for the life of me figure out how to subtract Sundays from that list. I know how to count business days and weekends separately, but how do i eliminate JUST Sundays?
Here is my formula:

```
days = 100
i = 1
daterange= []
while i < days:
    yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=i)
    daterange.append(yesterday.strftime('%m%d%y'))
    i +=1

print(daterange)
```

Any help on this stubborn issue is appreciated :) Thanks

Comment: Asking a question on stackoverflow. I tried google and then came here. I'd be stupid as hell to wander for hours in the dark out of pride instead of asking for help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `datetime.weekday()` to exclude Sundays.

```
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

days = 100
daterange = []

for i in range(1, 100):
    yesterday = datetime.now() - timedelta(days=i)
    if yesterday.weekday() != 6:
        daterange.append(yesterday.strftime('%m%d%y'))

print(*daterange, sep='\n')
```

Also, I'd rather use a `for` loop instead of a `while` loop here.